# Facial Recognition Using c# & EMGU CV Accuracy Problem

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, face-recognition

I have project code to create a face recognition system using EMGUCV. I have trained the database with 2 people. When the webcam detects those people and able to show the name correctly but the problem is the third person whose do not exist in trained database detect by webcam, it will take the nearest face and display the name on it instead of show "Unknown". How can I improve the accuracy? I have tried to change the threshold value but didn't help. What's going wrong?

```
 MCvFont font = new MCvFont(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 0.6d, 0.6d);
        HaarCascade faceDetected;
        Image<Bgr, Byte> Frame;
        Capture camera;
        Image<Gray, byte> result;
        Image<Gray, byte> TrainedFace = null;
        Image<Gray, byte> grayFace = null;
        List<Image<Gray, byte>> trainingImages = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();
        List<string> labels = new List<string>();
        List<string> Users = new List<string>();
        EigenObjectRecognizer recognizer;
        int Count, NumLabels, t;
        string name, names = null;



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PhotoPers.Image = Properties.Resources.EmptyPiC;
            //HaarCascade is for face detection
            faceDetected = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
            try
            {
                string Labelsinfo = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/Faces/Faces.txt");
                string[] Labels = Labelsinfo.Split(',');
                NumLabels = Convert.ToInt16(Labels[0]);
                Count = NumLabels;
                string LoadFaces;
            //    if (result)
            //    {
            //        CvInvoke.cvPutText(Frame, name[result.Labels], new Point(face.X - 2, face.Y - 2),
            //                        FontFace.HersheyComplex, 1.0, new Bgr(Color.Orange).MCvScalar);
            //        CvInvoke.cvRectangle(Frame, face, new Bgr(Color.Green).MCvScalar, 2);
            //}
                    for (int tf = 1; tf < NumLabels + 1; tf++)
                {
                    LoadFaces = "face" + tf + ".bmp";
                    trainingImages.Add(new Image<Gray, byte>(Application.StartupPath + "/Faces/" + LoadFaces));
                    labels.Add(Labels[tf]);

                  
                }
               

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                
            }
        }
        string imgLocation = " ";
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                camera = new Capture();
            camera.QueryFrame();
            
            Application.Idle += new EventHandler(FrameProcedure);
        }
            private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            byte[] images = null;
            FileStream Streem = new FileStream(imgLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader brs = new BinaryReader(Streem);
            images = brs.ReadBytes((int)Streem.Length);
            if (txtName.Text == "" || txtLName.Text == " " || txtIDNo.Text == " " || cboDepartment.Text == " ")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("All fields must be fillup!");
            }
            else
            {

                Count = Count + 1;
                grayFace = camera.QueryGrayFrame().Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
                MCvAvgComp[][] DetectedFaces = grayFace.DetectHaarCascade(faceDetected, 1.2, 10, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(20, 20));
                foreach (MCvAvgComp f in DetectedFaces[0])
                {
                    TrainedFace = Frame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, byte>();
                    break;
                }
                TrainedFace = result.Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
                trainingImages.Add(TrainedFace);    
                labels.Add(txtName.Text);
                File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/Faces/Faces.txt", trainingImages.ToArray().Length.ToString() + ",");

                for (int i = 1; i < trainingImages.ToArray().Length + 1; i++)
                {
                    trainingImages.ToArray()[i - 1].Save(Application.StartupPath + "/Faces/face" + i + ".bmp");
                    File.AppendAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/Faces/Faces.txt", labels.ToArray()[i - 1] + ",");

                
            }
        }
            mCon.ConOpen();

            string SaveStr = "INSERT INTO tblRegister (FirstName, LastName, IDno, Department, Image)" +
                             "VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @IDno, @Department, @Image)";

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(SaveStr, mCon.myCon);

            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtName.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLName.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDno", txtIDNo.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", cboDepartment.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", images);
            

            
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            
            mCon.ConClose();
            MessageBox.Show("Data has been Save!");

            txtName.Text = " ";
            txtLName.Text = " ";
            txtIDNo.Text = " ";
            cboDepartment.Text = " ";


        }

        private void PhotoPers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void FrameProcedure(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Users.Add("");
                Frame = camera.QueryFrame().Resize(500, 300, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
                grayFace = Frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
                MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetectedNow = grayFace.DetectHaarCascade(faceDetected, 1.2, 10, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(20, 20));
                foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetectedNow[0])
                {
                    result = Frame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, Byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
                    Frame.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(Color.Cyan), 3);
                    if (trainingImages.ToArray().Length != 0)
                    {
                        MCvTermCriteria termCriterias = new MCvTermCriteria(Count, 0.001);
                        EigenObjectRecognizer recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(trainingImages.ToArray(), labels.ToArray(), 4500, ref termCriterias);
                        name = recognizer.Recognize(result);
                    Frame.Draw(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? "UNKNOWN" : name, ref font, new Point(f.rect.X - 2, f.rect.Y - 2), new Bgr(Color.Red));

                }
                   

                Users.Add("");
                }
            CameraBox.Image = Frame;
            names = "";
                Users.Clear();
            }
        private void TrainImagesFromDir()
        {


            //string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Faces/Faces.txt";


            //Users.Add("");
            //Frame = camera.QueryFrame().Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
            //grayFace = Frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
            //MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetectedNow = grayFace.DetectHaarCascade(faceDetected, 1.2, 10, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(20, 20));
            //foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetectedNow[1])
            //{
            //    result = Frame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, Byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
            //    Frame.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);
            //    if (trainingImages.ToArray().Length != 0)
            //    {
            //        MCvTermCriteria termCriterias = new MCvTermCriteria(Count, 0.001);
            //        EigenObjectRecognizer recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(trainingImages.ToArray(), labels.ToArray(), 1500, ref termCriterias);
            //        name = recognizer.Recognize(result);
            //        Frame.Draw(name, ref font, new Point(f.rect.X - 2, f.rect.Y - 2), new Bgr(Color.Red));
        }
            private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
                dialog.Filter = "png files(*.png)|*.png|jpg files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                imgLocation = dialog.FileName.ToString();
                PhotoPers.ImageLocation = imgLocation;
            }
            }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know this framework so I'm not best to answer. But just one though. What kind of output is returned when you try to match a face? I assume it's a normalized value between 0 and 1. Usually in ML we are dealing with probability rather than right or wrong answers. So if you think of 0.9 being like 90% confidence and 0.1 being much lower confidence then you might need to add a threshold where the confidence is too low to give any match. If I'm right then it might be looking at person 3 and saying theres a 1% chance that it matches person 1, but it's still the closest match

Comment: works as intended. the eigen face recognizer is supposed to choose the best match, not assess the quality of the match. -- use a different approach. you need something that has been trained on LOTS OF FACES so it understands "faces", and how they vary (eigenvectors). if you train something on two faces, your entire space of faces is a single dimension.

Comment: can I ask what other approach can I use? Thank you

Comment: just use facenet. it gives you an "embedding" (feature vector). do some research on the problem.